# How to extract string at a certain character that is repeated within string?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get "MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties" and "Condo.gif" from a  "MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties.Condo.gif" string.

I also need it to be able to handle something like "MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties.legend.House.gif" and return "House.gif" and "MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties.legend".

IndexOf LastIndexOf wouldn't work because I need the second to last '.' character.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the answers so far but I really need it to be able to handle different namespaces.  So really what I'm asking is how to I split on the second to last character in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to do something like this:

```
string target = "MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties.legend.House.gif";

var elements = target.Split('.');

const int NumberOfFileNameElements = 2;

string fileName = string.Join(
    ".", 
    elements.Skip(elements.Length - NumberOfFileNameElements));

string path = string.Join(
    ".", 
    elements.Take(elements.Length - NumberOfFileNameElements));
```

This assumes that the file name part only contains a single `.` character, so to get it you skip the number of remaining elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a Regex or String.Split with '.' as the separator and return the second-to-last + '.' + last pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for `IndexOf("MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties.")`, add that to `MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties.".Length` and then `.Substring(..)` from that position

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly what you're looking for, and it's trailing, you could use [string.endswith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz.aspx). Something like

```
if("MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties.Condo.gif".EndsWith("Condo.gif"))
```

If that's not the case check out [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx). Then you could do something like

```
if(Regex.IsMatch("Condo.gif"))
```

Or a more generic way: split the string on '.' then grab the last two items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "MyLibrary.Resources.Images.Properties.legend.House.gif";
//if string isn't already validated, make sure there are at least two 
//periods here or you'll error out later on.
int index = input.LastIndexOf('.', input.LastIndexOf('.') - 1);
string first = input.Substring(0, index);
string second = input.Substring(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the string into an array, by separating it by each '.' character.

You will then have something like:

```
 {"MyLibrary", "Resources", "Images", "Properties", "legend", "House", "gif"}
```

You can then take the last two elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just break down and do it in a char loop:

```
int NthLastIndexOf(string str, char ch, int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) throw new ArgumentException();
    for (int idx = str.Length - 1; idx >= 0; --idx)
        if (str[idx] == ch && --n == 0)
            return idx;

    return -1;
}
```

This is less expensive than trying to coax it using string splitting methods and isn't a whole lot of code.

```
string s = "1.2.3.4.5";
int idx = NthLastIndexOf(s, '.', 3);
string a = s.Substring(0, idx); // "1.2"
string b = s.Substring(idx + 1); // "3.4.5"
```